# Magento SOAP api errror: Access denied

Tags: api, soap, fatal-error

I'm trying the following code to access product list

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->call($session, 'product.list');
$client->endSession($session);
```

But this is throwing the following error -

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied.

Can anyone help me to resolve this error ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check if the apiUser and apiKey are correct or maybe try to set a new key/password via **System > Web-Services > SOAP/XML-RPC - Users**.
- Disable WSDL Cache: Under **System > Configuration > Magento Core API** set Enable WSDL Cache to "No".
- Updated/debug your script:

Try to run your script with the WSDL cache disabled settings:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->call($session, 'product.list');
$client->endSession($session);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to 

1. create a new SOAP/XML-RPX Roles, say "Test" 

2. in Role Resources just select "All" for Resource Access (just for testing) 

3. Edit the user and assign the Role to "Test"